# Include UIImageView in PushRow Cells

Tags: eureka-forms

I would like to include an image and text in each ListCheckCell associated with a PushRow. The default behavior is to only display the text of each option. Ideally I would just override the ListCheckCell update() function but I have not found a clean way to do this because of the way ListCheckCell is built into PushRow through SelectorViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. To change cells within a PushRow ViewController there is a var on SelectViewController called selectableRowCellUpdate. Here is what my PushRow looks like:

```
<<< PushRow<SomeType>() {
            $0.title = "Category"

            $0.selectorTitle = "Category"

            }.onPresent { from, to in
                to.selectableRowCellUpdate = { (cell, row) in
                    let text = row.selectableValue?.toString()
                    let imageName = row.selectableValue?.rawValue
                    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: imageName!)
                    cell.textLabel?.text = text
                }
    }
```